# After importing a static library, some headers in the header cannot be found

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, static-libraries

My static library is an engine depending on other headers.

For example, in `XXXEngine.h`

```
#include "CommonUtil.h"
#include "DebugLogger.h"
```

All of these files are added when I build the static library. So I only export `XXXEngine.h` as the API and hide my implementations.

But the problem is that when I import that header file into another project and the `.a` file is already added as well, I get some errors saying that `"CommonUtil.h" cannot be found`. **It can find `XXXEngine.h`, but just not the headers inside this file**. But **I didn't want to expose those header files**.

What should I do to fix this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any header files that you `#include` in the header files that define your
library's API become part of your library's API. If the compiler ever has to
find `MyLib.h` then it has to find every header that is (recursively) `#include`-ed
in  `MyLib.h`.

So if you don't want to expose a particular header file and don't want your
library's users to need it, then you just can't include it in `MyLib.h`.

Instead of, e.g:-

**MyLib.h**

```
...
...

#include "private_header.h"
#include "public_header.h"

...
...
```

and

**MyLib.m**

```
#include "MyLib.h"

...
...
```

you need to refactor like:

**MyLib.h**

```
...
...

#include "public_header.h"

...
...
```

and

**MyLib.m**

```
#include "MyLib.h"
#include "private_header.h"

...
...
```

If your project will not compile like that, then it proves that `MyLib.h`
*does* need declarations from `private_header.h`, which you do not want it to expose.
In that case, rethink and refactor your code until it doesn't.